# How to remove an array element from compare to other array element?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays. I need to remove an element from the first array when the element is included in the second array.

e.g.:

```
$First = array("apple"=>"7", "orange"=>"8", "strawberry"=>"9", "lemon"=>"10", "banana"=>"11");

$Second = array("orange"=>"1", "lemon"=>"1","banana"=>"1");

$Result = array("apple"=>"7","strawberry"=>"9");
```

I've used the following code but it is not working:

```
foreach($Second as $key){
    $keyToDelete = array_search($key, $First);
    unset($First[$keyToDelete]);
}
print_r($First);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close!

Firstly,

```
foreach ($Second as $key)
```

will only give you the value. To get the key you have to do

```
foreach ($Second as $key => $value)
```

Loop through the $Second array and then if they key exists (use `isset`) in $First array remove it using `unset`. $Second will then be the same as $Results

```
foreach ($Second as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($First[$key])) {
        unset($First[$key]);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to keep $First and $Second as they are then you can do the following:

```
foreach ($Second as $key => $value) {
    if (!isset($First[$key])) {
        $Results[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you unset then you lost data.

Comment: but in my case data comes from db and i just used for show with remove duplication.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to eliminate duplicates on database level?

Comment: @fraynekonok I have updated my answer. If the key does not exist then store in $Results

Answer (score 7):

Use `array_diff_key` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php

```
$First = array("apple"=>"7", "orange"=>"8", "strawberry"=>"9", "lemon"=>"10", "banana"=>"11");
$Second = array("orange"=>"1", "lemon"=>"1","banana"=>"1");
$Result = array_diff_key($First, $Second);
```

Comment: nice answer. +1 up

Comment: my bad, changed to `array_diff_key` - checked it right now, result is same as desired by OP

Comment: also change the top portion